# Update the parameter for Realm is not working

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I defined the realm object like below.
I want to update only `prefectures` in `User` class.

```
class User: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = ""
    var countries = List<CountryObject>()
    var prefectures = List<PrefectureRealmObject>()
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class CountryObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = ""
    @objc dynamic var createdAt = Date()
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class PrefectureRealmObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = ""
    @objc dynamic var createdAt = Date()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

I think we can udpate only parameters to change the parameter of Realm object in write transaction.
I wrote like this.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
guard let userFromRealm = realm.objects(User.self).filter("id == %@", id).first else { return }
try! realm.write {
    userFromRealm.prefectures = user.prefectures
}
```

I observe the changes of realm database to write like this.
But the callback in `results.observe` function is never called when updating the Realm parameter.
What is the wrong?

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let id = IDService.getUserId() ?? IDService.createId()
let results = realm.objects(User.self).filter("id = %@", id)
notificationToken = results.observe { [weak self] (changes) in
    switch changes {
    case .initial(let updatedResult), .update(let updatedResult, deletions: _, insertions: _, modifications: _):
        break;
    case .error(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: My first guest is this `let id = IDService.getUserId() ?? IDService.createId()` is creating a new user id each time and therefore you're only observing the new user. Have you done some troubleshooting to ensure that's not the case?

Comment: Yes, it can be ignored.
getUserId() function returns optional id. It returns nil and save it as a UserDefaults only first time.
if we choose the different way, this code works so I think it's no problem.

Comment: That's kind vague, and storing the id in userdefaults is probably not the best idea (and not really what user defaults are for). I copy an pasted your code and it works flawlessly for us as long as the *id* var is a valid user id that exists in Realm and is guaranteed to be unique. You need to do that because of the .first may return a different object if the id's are the same.

Comment: I understand what you said.
But when I checked the number of realm.objects(User.self).filter("id == %@", id) and it's one, it's not working.
Looks the problem is not about to guarantee the value to be unique?

Comment: The code really doesn't look correct; this line `let id = IDService.getUserId() ?? IDService.createId()` gets a user id and if its nil it creates one? Then you're populating results with either one that exists or one that didn't? `let results = realm.objects(User.self).filter("id = %@", id)` Not sure what the goal was there since it would observe an id that didn't exist.